# Merge Conflicts and FAST FORWARD in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to set up a Merge conflict in git. When I try to resolve it, I do not see any Automerging failed message form git. It just displays fast-forward. How can I disable this and see all messages?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem here. Could you be more specific? Maybe describe the steps?

Comment: Share the commands you're using and the output you're getting

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge --no-ff OTHERBRANCH
```

This would not generate any conflicts since it can be fast forwarded.